# SimpleSAMLphp - SSO Azure works in Firefox and Safari, but not in Chrome and Edge

Tags: php, azure, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

We are trying to set up simpleSAMLphp to SSO against Azure AD, to use with a MediaWiki installation.

Desired situation: 
When someone logs into MediaWiki, that person should be redirected to Azure AD. Next, the user shoud fill in his credentials and be redirected to the wiki.

Current situation: 
I followed the steps as described here: https://medium.com/vivritiengineering/mediawiki-and-azure-single-sign-on-e3fbc13d1f46

SimpleSAMLphp is set up on an on-premise Debian server. 
Config.php and authsources.php are set up for Azure and our tenant .

We created an app in Azure and filled in 2 reply-URI's:

- https://**ourSite**/simplesaml/module.php/core/authenticate.php?as=default-sp
- https://**ourSite**/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp

Problem: 
In Firefox and Safari everything works: I go to "Test Configured Authentication Sources" - "default-sp". 
Next I'm presented with a Microsoft loginpage.
After logging in with my account, simpleSAMLphp shows me my metadata. As expected.

In Chrome and Edge, when going to 'Test configured authentication sources - default-sp' the page gets stuck in a redirect loop:

- https://login.microsoftonline.com/**newSamlRequest**
- https://**ourSite**/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp
- https://**ourSite**/simplesaml/module.php/core/authenticate.php?as=default-sp
- repeat

What I tried:

1. Clearing my cache and cookies. 
   **Result**: I'm presented the Microsoft login screen, but after submitting my credentials I get stuck in the loop.
2. Changing store.type in simpleSAMLphp from "phpSession" to "SQL" (tried both SQLite and MySQL). 
    **Result**: still works in Firefox and Safari. Loop in Chrome/Edge.
3. New application in Azure AD, same result
4. Different settings in simpleSAMLphp config.php 
   **Result**: sometimes broke simpleSAML, mostly same result as above.

I'm new with simpleSAMLphp and after a few days of trial-and-error I'm out of ideas (besides just abandoning simpleSAML and trying to switch to LDAP) 
It seems to be browser/cookie/cache related.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: In `config.php` check if 'session.cookie.samesite' is set, and if not set it => 'None'  Chrome requires it for cross site cookies to be posted, which may be your issue. Otherwise it seems like a cookie is getting lost in Edge and Chrome. You may need to use browser develop tools to snoop traffics and see when the SSP session cookie gets lost.

Comment: Solved by reinstalling simpleSAMLphp. and completly redo the configuration. Checked old and new conifg, but I can't see a difference. I did revert from simpleSAMLphp-v1.19.0 to simpleSAMLphp-v.1.18.8, but I'm hesitant to say that was the cause

Comment: It seems that this bug report refers to the issue: https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/issues/1444 - and it further seems that the samesite-cookie settings are the key.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by reinstalling simpleSAMLphp and completly redo the configuration.
Checked old and new conifg, but I can't see a difference.

I did revert from simpleSAMLphp-v1.19.0 to simpleSAMLphp-v.1.18.8, but I'm hesitant to say that was the cause.